# Reverse for 'register' not found. 'register' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to make a simple app that uses the django built-in User model. I have created a registration page, but when I run the server, I get this error at the index page. Here's the code I'm using:

Registration.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "basic/base.html" %}

{% block title_block %}
    <title>Registration</title>
{% endblock title_block %}

{% block body_block %}
    <div class="jumbotron">
        {% if registered %}
            <h1>Thank you for registering</h1>
        {% else %}
            <h1>Register here!</h1> 
            <h3>Fill out the form: </h3>

            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{userForm.as_p}}
                {{profileForm.as_p}}
                <input type="submit" value="Register" name="">
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock body_block %}
```

Views.py for the 'register' method

```
def register(request):

    registered = False

    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        userForm = forms.UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profileForm = forms.UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if((userForm.is_valid()) and (profileForm.id_valid())):
            user = userForm.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profileForm.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if('profileImage' in request.FILES):
                profile.profileImage = request.FILES['profileImage']

            profile.save()

            registered = True

        else:
            print(userForm.errors, profileForm.errors)

    else:
        userForm = forms.UserForm()
        profileForm = forms.UserProfileInfoForm()

    return render(request, 'basic/registration.html', {'userForm':userForm, 'profileForm':profileForm, 'registered':registered})
```

This is the urls.py for the project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from basic import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('basic/', include('basic.urls', namespace='basic'))
]
```

This is the urls.py for the basic app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'basic'

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register)
]
```

And the link to the page in base.html

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'basic:register' %}">Register</a>
```

What can cause the error here?

Comment: please mention the error and your dir structure

Comment: Post your urls.py file, that will solve the issue.

Comment: RE basic:register, is namespace and name variables defined properly in the urls.py file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must include a `name` argument to the register route.

```
path('register/', views.register, name='register')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Answer (score 2):

try this (inside your html file)

```
<a class="nav-link" href={% url 'basic:register' %}>Register</a>
```

and your urls.py (inside your app) as this:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('register/', views.register,name='register'),
]
```

this method worked for me I was fasing the same issue.